# Insert large amounts of text into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have encountered a problem while inserting a large amounts of text into my MySql database.

Can I please get any pointers (what column types to use & any other issues I need to know) as to how I can achieve this, the code works fine with small amounts.

Thanks in advance.

Clarification
The text blocks have around 7,000 characters.

And the problem I'm encountering is the PHP app is prompting me that the data has been saved but when i look at the dbase, the record hasnt been stored.

I have changed the particular column to LONG TEXT but that doesnt seem to do the trick.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some examples of where you are running into problems? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What problem did you encounter exactly? How wide is the column and how many characters are you trying to insert?

Comment: TEXT is sufficient for 7,000 characters, as this will hold up to 65535 bytes of data http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: I have found out what the problem was, thanks for the help and next time I will try to have clearer questions Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short use LONGBLOB or LONGTEXT, but you better descrive the problem more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

question is a bit vague but if you're using innodb and can bulk load here are a few tips:

```
sort your data file into the primary key order of the target table 
(innodb uses clustered primary keys)
```

typical load data infile i use:

```
truncate <table>;

set autocommit = 0;

load data infile <path> into table <table>...

commit;
```

other optimisations you can use to boost load times:

```
unqiue_checks = 0;
foreign_key_checks = 0;
sql_log_bin = 0;
split the csv file into smaller chunks
```

as far as datatypes are concerned:

use the smallest datatype you can tinyint unsigned vs int etc

as you're dealing with textual data favour varchar over text where possible.